# Docker build leaves intemediate images

Tags: php, image, docker, build, composer-php

I want to build on my own composer:latest image with Docker version 18.06.1-ce, I use this script to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

wget -O Dockerfile https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/docker/edf4f0abf50da5d967408849434b9053a195b65f/1.7/Dockerfile
wget -O docker-entrypoint.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/docker/master/1.7/docker-entrypoint.sh
chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
docker build -t mycomposer:latest .
```

but besides the created image

> mycomposer:latest

i end up having around 10 images none:none.

```
docker image prune
```

does not solve the issue.

how to build the composer:latest image form the files here [composer github](https://github.com/composer/docker/tree/master/1.7) without leaving these intermediate images?

I want to do it manually instead of using command FROM because this is the first step of me using Dockerfile as a template and add,delete commands to/from it where I want. But the first step is to get the image build as it is from local Docker file instead of using FROM command. I don't want to use FROM command because it implies using all the commands in Dockerfile and i want just a few of them as a starting point to my custom Dockerfile and some others edited from which I'll be building my own image.

currently I managed to build image using local Dockerfile but there is a lot of unnecessary images none:none

[image: Actual repository]

instead of having repository like that:
[image]

where there is just one image after build. The single image from the picture above comes from the command:

docker pull composer:latest

but this pulls composer image instead of building it from my local Dockerfile, so it does not fill the bill.

But how come there is just single image after the command pull and several ones after doing build from the same Dockerfile as pull takes (I assume) and how to get rid of these none:none images?

Comment: How exactly are you seeing these "none:none" images?  What specific command are you running?

Comment: edited post and added screen dumps to show wanted/actual result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker images are made of *layers*; each has a piece of the combined ultimate image filesystem.  The layers actually make up a kind of tree, where you might have a base Ubuntu layer, with a child that installs a specific Debian package, with a child that adds your application code, and so on.  Each of these layers is actually independently usable as an image, but you can't delete a base-layer image so long as there's another image below it that depends on it.

You're running `docker image -a`, which lists *all* of the images, even the ones that only exist as base layers.  That produces a bunch of "extra" `<none> <none>` images, which are the base layers.  They're harmless, and required, and don't take up any extra resources.  In general using the `-a` option doesn't really tell you anything and I'd just skip it.

Answer (score 3):

The images are the build cache. They allow docker to dramatically speed up future builds of the same image. Their actual disk usage is near 0 because the layers are shared between the images, the only impact is some json metadata and directories. Once you build another image and untag the previously built image, a prune will remove the unused dangling images.

Comment: makes sense, even if I look at the docker image repository as at picture above where is plenty of none:none images at the very bottom there is `php:7-alpine3.7` that the `composer:latest` image is build FROM, but how exactly get rid of these intermediate images (or layers)? do you have any command for that?

Comment: If you delete the layers, you destroy your final image. What is your goal in deleting these intermediate images? Do you need to remove the few kb of meta data, or do you want to prevent the build from using the cache next time?

Comment: I was looking at the images pulled (not build) and I did not see any intermediate layers. I though that building image locally would provide the same effect - just one image without any intermediate layers but as far as I understood if i build image locally I just get these layers into repository as a must building blocks of the final image that I want and I can't opt out from having them - is that right?

Comment: I still don't understand your goals behind removing these intermediate images. What are you hoping to achieve by removing them?

Comment: just didn't want to have a mess in docker images listing, but if they are part of images build and I cant remove them I can live with that. I was under the impression that building an image should result in having just the one, final image similar to the `dokcer pull` command that does not create in the docker any intermediate layers but just puts there the image you pulled. If you pull an image you get just that image in docker images listing,I thought that build would do the same from local Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to build an image from Dockerfile:

clone the repo from the github.

```
git clone https://github.com/composer/docker.git .
cd 1.7 
docker build -t mycomposer:latest .
```

That's it.

Comment: It builds image. You missed dot, should be in the first line `git clone https://github.com/composer/docker.git .` but even i managed to get docker image build this way as well it does not solve the problem of intermediate images left in repository

Comment: @Jimmix while cloning the repo, you don't need the dot. You only need the dot while building the image & that means you use the Dockerfile in the local directory.

Comment: the thing is about the second line `cd 1.7`. When you do `git clone` you firstly get created dir that is the name of the repo and within that repo you have directory `1.7` so the line `cd 1.7` does not work because you either do it `cd repo-name/1.7` or you put dot at the end of `git clone` so clone does not create the repo directory where it puts all the files but just puts them into current dir instead and `cd 1.7` will work

Comment: @Jimmix that was my mistake. I forgot to change the directory to docker since I'm cloning **docker** repo from the github.
Thanks :)
I didn't know about the dot(.) notation before.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#docker-objects

> Each instruction in a Dockerfile creates a layer in the image. When you change the Dockerfile and rebuild the image, only those layers which have changed are rebuilt. This is part of what makes images so lightweight, small, and fast, when compared to other virtualization

Hence `docker image prune` won't remove them. Without those layers, your image won't work.